# Animation grass with Gscatter

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, animation-nodes

I'm new in blender and i've some issues to animate grass from gscatter.

I add a transform geometry but it rotate all the assets.

I want a rotation 1 by 1.

Do you have a solution ?

[image]

Comment: That's a third-party addon so questions about it are off-topic here. There seem to be quite a few YT tutorials on using it online so I suggest you Google the addon name.